# scopus keywords and citations crawling

Tags: python, web-crawler, scopus

I'm trying to crawling articles' data from Scopus api. 
I have api key and can receive fields from Standard view.

Here is example:

Firstly, initialization (api, searching query and headers)

```
import json
import requests

api_resource = "https://api.elsevier.com/content/search/scopus?"
search_param = 'query=title-abs-key(big data)'  # for example

# headers
headers = dict()
headers['X-ELS-APIKey'] = api_key
headers['X-ELS-ResourceVersion'] = 'XOCS'
headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
```

Now I can receive article json (for example, first article from first page):

```
# request with first searching page
page_request = requests.get(api_resource + search_param, headers=headers)
# response to json
page = json.loads(page_request.content.decode("utf-8"))
# List of articles from this page
articles_list = page['search-results']['entry']

article = articles_list[0]
```

I can easily get some main fields from standard view:

```
title = article['dc:title']
cit_count = article['citedby-count']
authors = article['dc:creator']
date = article['prism:coverDate']
```

However, I need keywords and citations of this article.
I solved problem with keywords with additional request to article's url:

```
article_url = article['prism:url']
# something like this:
# 'http://api.elsevier.com/content/abstract/scopus_id/84909993848'
```

with field=authkeywords

```
article_request = requests.get(article_url + "?field=authkeywords", headers=headers)
article_keywords = json.loads(article_request.content.decode("utf-8"))
keywords = [keyword['$'] for keyword in article_keywords['abstracts-retrieval-response']['authkeywords']['author-keyword']]
```

This method works, but sometimes keywords are missing. Also, scopus api-key has limit of requests (10000 per week), and this way not optimal.

**Can I make it easier?**

Next question about citations. To find citations of articles, I'm send one more request again, by use article['eid'] field:

```
citations_response = requests.get(api_resource + 'query=refeid(' + str(article['eid']) + ')', headers=headers)
citations_result = json.loads(citations_response.content.decode("utf-8"))
citations = citations_result['search-results']['entry']  # list of citations
```

**So, can I get citations, without additional request?**

Comment: You're getting references (articles cited by the article you got) in that way, not citations (articles referencing the article you got) . I am also looking for a way to get citations from the scopus api, but i don't think is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can get references with a single query only with a COMPLETE view.
(subscriber only)

Comment: Note: FULL view will only show partial infos on the references, for more info such as author's id you need the REF view.